# Electric tankless water heater as preheat system before gas tank water heater

Tags: water-heater

I have an apartment building with 12 units and a laundry room with 6 washer and dryers. I am about to install a solar PV system, and see this as my chance to reduce my gas bill by taking the load off of my 100 gallon gas water heater. My idea is to size the solar to include the load added by installing a 36 kW electric tankless water heater on the cold line return, before the 100 gallon tank. This would warm the water before it goes the the tank, thereby reducing the load on the gas burners. Will this work?
Tony

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but my guess is that no way will you get enough power from your solar panels to make a difference. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: This sounds like you need a better gas heater here.  What make and model is the existing 100 gallon tank?

Comment: Will this solar system be grid-tied, and are you using net metering (you get paid as much for generated solar as you pay for power)?

Comment: It could work but it will only work during the day and do you realize how many panels it will take to push 36kw wow. The cost of that solar that will only work or be available 8-10 hours a day. So all that $ spent for the capacity to run a massive electric water heater will never pay for itself. Gas is one of the cheapest ways to heat water. If you wanted to run the electric on mains power when their is not enough daylight your service will probably need to be upsized. The only plus is if your utility allows you to sell the excess electricity through a grid tied system it might pay off in 20yr